# NSBundle doesn't load dynamic resources

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem reading a Strings file created dynamically inside my app's document directory. 
Basically, I create and read my file using:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:fileData attributes:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [targetBundle localizedStringForKey:@"MY_STRING" value:@"#" table:@"test"]);
```

The file is created in the document directory, and the targetBundle also points to this directory. 
The above code works very well when the strings file already exists in the document directory when the app runs.
So, if I delete the Strings file from the document directory, the NSLog displays: #.
When I run again the application (the file already exists), NSLog displays MY_LABEL's value.

I guess that the bundle loads its resources once at the launch, but how can I be sure to read my new file even if it has just been created?

Thank you for your help,

Julian

Comment: This might be silly, but since the bundle is loaded into memory ... have you tried reloading the bundle? Observe changes made to the file (look into `FNSubscribe`) and reload the bundle when necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I think the solution is about the reloading of my bundle but I don't know how to reload it properly. What is FnSubscribe?

Comment: Write in a file might be asynchronous, that's why you don't get the changes the next line.

Comment: Thank you Crazyrems, but it would work in debugging mode?

Comment: `FNSubscribe` observes changes made to certain files you're interested in. A quick Google search should yield some examples.

Comment: I didn't know this lib. Interesting. In my case, I know when the file changes, but the content doesn't seem to be applied through the bundle. I know when the bundle has to be reloaded but I don't know how to reload it.

Comment: If you know when the bundle is reloaded, then a simple invocation of `NSBundle`'s `load` selector should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to reload a bundle but I fixed this problem by creating an empty file with the same name BEFORE the creation of the bundle. 
With that, the bundle "knows" the file and if the file dynamically changes, the content is up-to-date (because the file is read at runtime).